# d3 multi-line voronoi, trouble with showing data on mouseover

Tags: d3.js

I've created a multiline chart and I want to use voronoi tessellation to handle mouseover. Here's a block with the code (which is what's also pasted below): http://bl.ocks.org/jhubley/c673e664379f964b357c

I'm using this block by Mike Bostock as a template: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015

I have the voronoi set up, but my mouseover isn't working. My data's structured differently than in the example block, and I'm struggling, though I feel it should be simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
                #graph{
                    width:80%;
                    height:200px;
                }
                g.crop{
                    width:900px;
                    height:200px;
                }

                #graph .axis path {
                fill: none;
                stroke: #ccc;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
                }
                #graph .axis text {
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 13px;
                    fill:#333;
                }
                .axis path,
                .axis line {
                    fill: #888888;
                    stroke: #000;
                    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
                }
                .corn{
                    stroke:#ff3300;
                }
                .apples{
                    stroke:#7ac000;
                }
                .wheat{
                    stroke:#0088c0;
                }
                .focus text {
                  text-anchor: middle;
                  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
                }

                .voronoi path {
                  fill: none;
                  pointer-events: all;
                }
                .voronoi--show path {
                  stroke: red;
                  stroke-opacity: .2;
                }
                .line-hover {
                  stroke: #000;
                    stroke-width:3;
                }
                </style>
                <title>Graph, Voronoi</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <label id="form" for="show-voronoi">
                  Show Voronoi
                  <input type="checkbox" id="show-voronoi" disabled>
                </label>

                <svg id="graph"></svg>
                <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
                <script>
            d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
                    data.forEach(function(d) {
                        d.Year = +d.Year;
                        d.number = +d.number;
                      });

                    var graph = d3.select("#graph")

                    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([100, 980]).domain([1990,2000]),   
                    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([180, 20]).domain([0,225]),

                    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format('0f')),
                    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

                    graph.append("svg:g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(0,180)")
                        .attr("class", "axis")
                        .call(xAxis);

                        graph.append("svg:g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)")
                        .attr("class", "axis")
                        .call(yAxis);

                        var kind = d3.nest()
                              .key(function(d) { return d.type; })
                              .entries(data);

                        var vor = d3.nest()
                        .key(function(d) { return xScale(d.Year) + "," + yScale(d.number); })
                              .rollup(function(v) { return v[0]; })
                              .entries(d3.merge(kind.map(function(d) { return d.values; })))
                              .map(function(d) { return d.values; });

                        console.log(vor);

                        var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
                                    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.Year); })
                                    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.number); })
                                    .clipExtent([[100,0], [1000,200]]);

                        var line = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d){return xScale(d.Year);})
                        .y(function(d){return yScale(d.number);});

                        graph.append("g")
                        .attr("class", "crops")
                        .selectAll("path")
                        .data(kind)
                        .enter().append("path")
                              .attr("class", function(d){return "crop " + d.key; })                     
                                    .attr("fill", "none")
                                    .attr("d", function(d){ d.line = this; return line(d.values); });

                        var focus = graph.append("g")
                          .attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)")
                          .attr("class", "focus");

                      focus.append("circle")
                          .attr("r", 3.5);

                      focus.append("text")
                          .attr("y", -10);

                      var voronoiGroup = graph.append("g")
                          .attr("class", "voronoi");

                        voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
                  .data(voronoi(vor))
                  .enter().append("path")
                  .attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; })
                  .datum(function(d) { return d.value; })
                  .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                  .on("mouseout", mouseout);

                        d3.select("#show-voronoi")
                                      .property("disabled", false)
                                      .on("change", function() { voronoiGroup.classed("voronoi--show", this.checked); });


                        function mouseover(d) {
                      d3.select('.crop').classed("line-hover", true);
                      focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.Year) + "," + yScale(d.number) + ")");
                      focus.select("text").text(d.number);
                              }

                        function mouseout(d) {
                      d3.select('.crop').classed("line-hover", false);
                      focus.attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");
                              }


        });

                    </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

My data:

```
"Year","type","number"
1990,"corn",4
1990,"apples",242
1990,"wheat",45
1991,"corn",211
1991,"apples",6
1991,"wheat",7
1992,"corn",8
1992,"apples",9
1992,"wheat",10
1993,"corn",11
1993,"apples",223
1993,"wheat",124
1994,"corn",14
1994,"apples",15
1994,"wheat",16
1995,"corn",17
1995,"apples",18
1995,"wheat",19
1996,"corn",20
1996,"apples",220
1996,"wheat",22
1997,"corn",152
1997,"apples",24
1997,"wheat",25
1998,"corn",206
1998,"apples",12
1998,"wheat",28
1999,"corn",128
1999,"apples",30
1999,"wheat",31
2000,"corn",32
2000,"apples",33
2000,"wheat",34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed the d.datum assignment:

```
voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
    .data(voronoi(vor))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
    })
    .datum(function(d) {          
      return d.value; //<------------- this should be d.point
    })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

And that's causing no data to be passed into your mouseover.  Once you change that back the correct data is passed in and your mouseover becomes:

```
  function mouseover(d) {
    d3.select('.'+d.type).classed("line-hover", true);
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.Year) + "," + yScale(d.number) + ")");
    focus.select("text").text(d.number);
  }
```

and mouseout:

```
  function mouseout(d) {
    d3.select('.'+d.type).classed("line-hover", false);
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(-100,-100)");
  }
```

Fixed code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCozxKYF1npTiRd5AjZC?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark! Much appreciated!